# How to "copy the Oracle JDBC driver into sonarqube_extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle"?

Tags: sonarqube

I’m setting up Sonarqube according to Install the server and there I see a very strange instruction:
a. Start the SonarQube container with the embedded H2 database:

```
$ docker run --rm \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    -v sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions \
    <image_name>
```

b. Exit once SonarQube has started properly.

c. Copy the Oracle JDBC driver into sonarqube_extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle.**

Where can I get JDBC driver and how to put it in `sonarqube_extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle`?

Nothing. I don't know where to get JDBC driver and how to put it in `sonarqube_extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle`.

Comment: You can get Oracle JDBC drivers either from the download page (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) or from Maven central repo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to download driver jar file from URL: https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html, and copy this to sonarqube_extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).